# Do somthing with $(this) element after certain time

Tags: jquery, html

I have forms with input "datapicker".... and it is annoying that I do not see the input errors because the inputs have attribute "readonly".

So I have this code:

```
$('p.send-app-btn input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(){
$('input').each(function(){
if ( $(this).is('[readonly]') && $(this).prop('required') && !$(this).val()) {
    $(this).removeAttr('readonly');

if($(this).is(':focus') && $(this).hasClass('hasDatepicker')){
  setTimeout(function () {
$(this).attr('readonly','readonly');
}, 1500);  
}
}
})
});
```

and it works well, because it removes the attribute "readonly" from `$(this)` input and input error is displaying. But I would like that after 1.5s (after error is gone) the focused input will be "readonly" again.

But this part of the code doesn't work because I cannot catch `$(this)` - how can I do it in another way?

```
if($(this).is(':focus') && $(this).hasClass('hasDatepicker')){
      setTimeout(function () {
    $(this).attr('readonly','readonly');
    }, 1500);  
    }
```

I hope it is clear. :)

Comment: have you heard about variables?!

Comment: No.. what does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help @Ulrich-dohou i found the solution for this:

```
$('input').each(function(){
if ( $(this).is('[readonly]') && $(this).prop('required') && !$(this).val()) {
    $(this).removeAttr('readonly');
    setTimeout(() => {
$(this).attr('readonly','readonly');
},1500)
}
})
```

Just my code checked the `$(this).is(':focus')` in moment of push the submit button. It was enought to check it litte bit late (enought 1s) and it works well. Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add `$(this)` to a variable or just use arrow function if your browser support **ES6**. Another example is that you create a function that will handle the action for you.

**Example 1**

```
if($(this).is(':focus') && $(this).hasClass('hasDatepicker')){
    const input = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
      input.attr('readonly', true);
    }, 1500);  
}
```

**Example 2**

```
if($(this).is(':focus') && $(this).hasClass('hasDatepicker')){
    setTimeout(() => {
      $(this).attr('readonly', true);
    }, 1500);  
}
```

**Example 3**

```
function disabeInput(element){
    element.attr('readonly', true);
}
if($(this).is(':focus') && $(this).hasClass('hasDatepicker')){
    setTimeout(() => {
      disabeInput($(this));
    }, 1500);  
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! I tried all of it and any example doesnt work.. They do not set attribute ('readonly') for this input...

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `this` as a parameter to the `setTimeout` function -

```
setTimeout(function(_this) {
  _this.attr('readonly','readonly');
}, 1500, $(this));
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. I tried it, but it does not set attribute for this input... :/